# Русский язык в iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Я хочу вытянуть из сайта определенную часть и сделать из этого куска pdf документ. Создаю документ по примеру из официального сайта iText:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

ElementList allElements = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(html, null);

for (Element element : allElements) {
cell.addElement(element);
}

table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
document.close();
```

Документ создается, но русские слова не отображается. Частично удалось решить таким способом:

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(FONT_LOCATION, ENCODING, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(title, new Font(baseFont, 18));
```

Но это для одного элемента, а метод `XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList()` возвращается уже созданный список.

Comment: Похожий вопрос на enSO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254628/set-encoding-when-converting-text-file-to-pdf-using-itext

Comment: Вопрос похож только тематикой. Автор вопроса создает элементы сам, а я их получаю из функции.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Element element : allElements) {
    for (Chunk c : e.getChunks()) {
        c.setFont(someFont);
    }
    cell.addElement(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Помните, что `XMLWorker` является устаревшим. Вы должны использовать `pdfHTML` для преобразования HTML в PDF. `pdfHTML` поддерживает `HTML5` и `CSS3`. И много улучшений было сделано к алгоритмам плана и таблицы.

Взгляните на
https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML